# off-topic how to make stylish editing a line?

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I have a file in which I have to change some lines that meet a certain rules

N1 N2 N3 r

where n1 n2 and n3 are the numbers that have value between 0 and 1 (with decimals)

e.g.

> 1 0.67 0 r
>
> 0.66 5 high
>
> 0 1 0.989 r
>
> 0.96 5 slow
>
> 0.23 0.345 0.65 r
>
> 1 1 1 1 1 1CB
>
> 0 0 0.9 r

these strings must be replaced with a string value of "0 0 0 r"
omitting the strings with the value "1 1 1 r"
this

```
var fs = require('fs');
var async = require('async');
async.waterfall([
    function(data,callback){
        fs.readFile('test.txt', function (err, data) {
            if (err) throw err;
            callback(null, data);
        });
    },
    function(data,callback){
        var expR =/\b(0\.\d*|[0-1])\s(0\.\d*|[0-1])\s(0\.\d*|0)\sr\b|\b(0\.\d*|[0-1])\s(0\.\d*|[0])\s(0\.\d*|[0-1])\sr\b|\b(0\.\d*|[0])\s(0\.\d*|[0-1])\s(0\.\d*|[0-1])\sr\b/gi;
        var dataBn = data.toString().replace(expR, '0 0 0 r');
        callback(null, dataBn); 
    },
    function(data,callback){
        fs.writeFile('test.ps', data, function(err){
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
                callback(err,err);
            } else {
                console.log("The file was saved!"); 
            }
        })
    }],
    function(err, result){
        console.log(result);
        if(err){/* not handle */}
    })
```

this is my output

> 0 0 0 r
>
> 0.66 5 high
>
> 0 0 0 r
>
> 0.96 5 slow
>
> 0 0 0 r
>
> 1 1 1 1 1 1CB
>
> 0 0 0 r

it works and also very quickly, but I was wondering if it was possible a solution a bit more elegant to change those lines ... suggestions?

*P.S. I used the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall) library to synchronize the read and write.
I did a bit of research  and I found very interesting the solution to read line by line, but I noticed a huge slowdown*

Comment: Could you add the expected output as well? It would make reading easier without going through your program.

Comment: your RegExp can accept `0. 0. 0. r` is it normal behavior?

Comment: yes....Unfortunately it is not always marked zero and the line could also arrive with 0.0 but without the last zero 0

Comment: in case discover the criterion of those lines 
maybe we will change * in +

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs to codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: The only thing I could do is to improve a bit your RegExp: `/\b(?:(?:(?:0\.\d+|[01])\s){2}(?:0\.\d+|0)\sr|(?:0\.\d+|[01])\s(?:0\.\d+|0)\s(?:0\.\d+|[01])\sr|(?:0\.\d+|0)\s(?:(?:0\.\d+|[01])\s){2}r)\b/gi`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this pattern:

```
var res = data.replace(/^(?!1 1 1)(?:(?:0(?:\.[0-9]*)?|1) ){3}r$/gm, '0 0 0 r');
```

details:

The pattern use anchors `^` and `$` with the m modifier to be sure to describe a whole line.

`(?!1 1 1)` is a negative lookahead that ensures that you are not in the case 1 1 1 r

`0(?:\.[0-9]*)?|1` describes the possible numbers (a zero followed or not with a dot followed or not with digits or a 1.)

Then I putted this in a group, added a space and repeated three times and putted an "r" at the end.

Comment: Unfortunately, reading the entire file I noticed that he lost the concept of start line and end line
For this reason I used "\ b"

Comment: @beginner's_luck: What you say is a little strange, are you sure these lines don't have trailing spaces?

Comment: usually are no spaces